# Finding time taken for a ball to reach the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I am a little bit confused in this question about finding $t$. I need to find $t$ in order to use my formula (to find s). The mark scheme has said that $t=6x\dfrac1{20}$ which gives a straight off 0.3, but up to knowledge I tried $t=20/60$ which gave me a repeated 0.33 and that made a lot of differences the final answer.

I just need to know what is the concept behind the $t=6x\dfrac1{20}$, why are the multiplying 1/20 by 6?? I need to understand the reason behind this. Please help.[image]

Comment: Hi Seyed and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Look at the photo. It shows the ball at 1/20-second intervals. How many images are there after X to arrive at Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in observation and experiment setup. It uses an old fashioned film camera in a darkened room and a black background. A strobe light is flashing 20 times per second as the ball is bounced. The images of the ball are consecutive in time and 1/20 second apart.

You simply count the images to find the time. In the this case there are 6 images from X to Y and someone calculated 6/20 of a second. This is probably incorrect I might add. There are indeed 6 images, which define 5 intervals of 1/20 second each, or 0.25 sec.

Anyway, v at the top of the bounce is zero in the vertical direction and the simplest acceleration formula will give the distance fallen, given you know the time.

Extra points: From the photo, why would it be more accurate to say the time is 11/40 sec?

Comment: I count 6 images *after*  X and *including* Y for 6 intervals...

Comment: @DJohnM X and the image following it appear to be at the same height.